# When I click the Pin not get the correct data. Solution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a problem when I click on a pin are not sent the correct data. From what I understand even though it has a NSUInteger, these are always changing. How can I fix?

The code is:

**DisplayMap.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface DisplayMap : NSObject <MKAnnotation> 

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *icon;


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Telefono;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Sito;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *TipologiaLocale;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Cucina;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Vegano;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Valutazione;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Latitudine;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Longitudine;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *FaceB;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Twit;

@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile *Anteprima1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile *Anteprima2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile *Anteprima3;

@end
```

**DisplayMap.m**

```
#import "DisplayMap.h"


@implementation DisplayMap

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;
@synthesize icon;

@end
```

**Alberghi.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

#import "Reachability.h"
#import "TestFlight.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "DisplayMap.h"
#import "Recipe.h"
#import "DettagliAlberghi.h"

@interface Alberghi : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

    MKMapView *_mapView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CLGeocoder *geoCoder;

- (IBAction)TornaHome:(id)sender;

@end
```

**Alberghi.m**

```
#import "Alberghi.h"

@interface Alberghi ()

@end

@implementation Alberghi

@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize geoCoder;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        _mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 415)];
        [_mapView setDelegate:self];
        _mapView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

        locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {

            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }

        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        _mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
        [_mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [_mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
        [_mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [self.view addSubview:_mapView];


        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Ristoranti"];

        [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

            if (!error)
            {

                //NSLog(@"QUERY -----> :%@", objects);


                for(NSDictionary *note1 in objects) {
                    float realLatitude1 = [[note1 objectForKey:@"Latitudine"] floatValue];
                    float realLongitude1 = [[note1 objectForKey:@"Longitudine"] floatValue];

                    NSLog(@"(PARSE) Latitudine: %f", realLatitude1);
                    NSLog(@"(PARSE) Longitudine: %f", realLongitude1);

                    DisplayMap *displayMap = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];

                    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
                    theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude1;
                    theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude1;
                    displayMap.coordinate = theCoordinate;
                    displayMap.title = [note1 objectForKey:@"NomeLocale"];
                    displayMap.subtitle = [note1 objectForKey:@"Indirizzo"];
                    displayMap.icon = [note1 objectForKey:@"PinMappa"];
                    [_mapView setDelegate:self];
                    [_mapView addAnnotation:displayMap];
                }
            }
        }];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[DisplayMap class]])
    {

        return nil;
    }

    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

    MKAnnotationView *pinView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

    if (pinView == nil)
    {
        pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

    }
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.annotation = annotation;

    DisplayMap *myAnn = (DisplayMap *)annotation;
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myAnn.icon];



    // Create a UIButton object to add on the
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pinView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];

    return pinView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    if ([(UIButton*)control buttonType] == UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Prova" sender:view];


    }
}

#pragma mark - mappa

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    for (MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views) {

        if (annotationView.annotation == mapView.userLocation) {
            MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1.4, 1.4);
            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, span);
            [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)TornaHome:(id)sender
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TornaHome" sender:self];
}



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Prova"]) {



        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = sender;



        DettagliAlberghi *destViewController =(DettagliAlberghi *) segue.destinationViewController;

        DisplayMap *displayMap = (DisplayMap *)annotationView.annotation;

        NSLog(@"DisplayMap? %@", displayMap);


        NSLog(@"Dettagli Ristorante:\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@
        \n%@", displayMap.title, displayMap.subtitle, displayMap.Telefono, displayMap.Email, 
        displayMap.Sito, displayMap.TipologiaLocale, displayMap.Cucina, displayMap.Vegano, 
        displayMap.Valutazione, displayMap.Latitudine, displayMap.Longitudine, 
        displayMap.Anteprima1, displayMap.Anteprima2, displayMap.Anteprima3, displayMap.FaceB,
        displayMap.Twit);

        destViewController.recipe = displayMap;






        /*
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = sender;

        NSLog(@"Esporto i dati: %@", annotationView);

        DettagliAlberghi *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        DisplayMap *displayMap = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];

        displayMap.title = [sender objectForKey:@"NomeLocale"];
        displayMap.subtitle = [sender objectForKey:@"Indirizzo"];
        displayMap.icon = [sender objectForKey:@"PinMappa"];
        displayMap.Telefono = [sender objectForKey:@"Telefono"];
        displayMap.Email = [sender objectForKey:@"Email"];
        displayMap.Sito = [sender objectForKey:@"Sito"];
        displayMap.TipologiaLocale = [sender objectForKey:@"TipologiaLocale"];
        displayMap.Cucina = [sender objectForKey:@"Cucina"];
        displayMap.Vegano = [sender objectForKey:@"Vegano"];
        displayMap.Valutazione = [sender objectForKey:@"Valutazione"];
        displayMap.Latitudine = [sender objectForKey:@"Latitudine"];
        displayMap.Longitudine = [sender objectForKey:@"Longitudine"];
        displayMap.Anteprima1 = [sender objectForKey:@"Anteprima1"];
        displayMap.Anteprima2 = [sender objectForKey:@"Anteprima2"];
        displayMap.Anteprima3 = [sender objectForKey:@"Anteprima3"];
        displayMap.FaceB = [sender objectForKey:@"Facebook"];
        displayMap.Twit = [sender objectForKey:@"Twitter"];




        NSLog(@"Dettagli Ristorante: \n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@", displayMap.title, displayMap.subtitle, displayMap.Telefono, displayMap.Email, displayMap.Sito, displayMap.TipologiaLocale, displayMap.Cucina, displayMap.Vegano, displayMap.Valutazione, displayMap.Latitudine, displayMap.Longitudine, displayMap.Anteprima1, displayMap.Anteprima2, displayMap.Anteprima3, displayMap.FaceB, displayMap.Twit);




        destViewController.recipe = displayMap;
        */

    }
}

@end
```

When I click on the pin, the app crashes. I added an NSLog in PrepareToSegue and I noticed that all the fields to export in View next are empty, however, the data is read through PFQuery in viewDidLoad. What's wrong? When I click the pin does not export the data required?

```
2014-11-29 08:08:16.190 Veg[1083:8473] (PARSE) Latitudine: 45.435745
2014-11-29 08:08:16.190 Veg[1083:8473] (PARSE) Longitudine: 10.986951
2014-11-29 08:08:16.191 Veg[1083:8473] (PARSE) Latitudine: 45.441578
2014-11-29 08:08:16.191 Veg[1083:8473] (PARSE) Longitudine: 10.982130
2014-11-29 08:08:29.102 Veg[1083:8473] DisplayMap? <DisplayMap: 0x7f90335b71f0>
2014-11-29 08:08:29.102 Veg[1083:8473] Dettagli Ristorante: 
La Lanterna
Piazzetta Portichetti, 6 Verona
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
2014-11-29 08:08:29.301 Veg[1083:8473] Double Coord: 0.000000, 0.000000
2014-11-29 08:08:31.356 Veg[1083:8473] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

I can not understand how to order ... always in the same order every time you open the View are always changing position and consequently when I click on a Pin View opens me different and not the one you want. Solutions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update, add this in your viewDidLoad (in ViewController):

```
            displayMap.icon = [note1 objectForKey:@"PinMappa"];

            // Add this

            displayMap.Telefono = [note1 objectForKey:@"Telefono"];
            displayMap.Email = [note1 objectForKey:@"Email"];
            displayMap.Sito = [note1 objectForKey:@"Sito"];
            displayMap.FaceB = [note1 objectForKey:@"Facebook"];
            displayMap.Twit = [note1 objectForKey:@"Twitter"];
            displayMap.Cucina = [note1 objectForKey:@"Cucina"];
            displayMap.TipologiaLocale = [note1 objectForKey:@"TipologiaLocale"];
            displayMap.Valutazione = [note1 objectForKey:@"Valutazione"];
            displayMap.Vegano = [note1 objectForKey:@"Vegano"];

            // End of adding

            [_mapView setDelegate:self];
```

Hi I assume you are using ARC, I'm afraid you have copied your code from a very old font, In fact a couple of them. (On example you have three instances variable what's name is title, one for the Protocol, and a couple of them on created an other from the property, with wrong synthesised). And the dealloc method better don't speak. 
Well change your code to this: (Don´t worry It has the same variable you need (without duplicates).

DispalyMap.h:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
 #import <Parse/Parse.h>

 @interface DisplayMap : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *icon;


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Telefono;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Sito;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *TipologiaLocale;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Cucina;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Vegano;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Valutazione;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Latitudine;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Longitudine;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *FaceB;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Twit;

@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile *Anteprima1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile *Anteprima2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile *Anteprima3;

@end
```

Display.m: (Only this)

```
@implementation DisplayMap

@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;
@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize subtitle = _subtitle;

@end
```

Well, I need to help you the crash message (because If with this change your App don't work, probably the mistake could be in the new view controller).

// Old answer:

I can't understand your code 100% because there are some code missing, but I think you made lot´s of thing you don't need. Try this methods, (Comment your current methods, and paste this).

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[DisplayMap class]])
{

    return nil;
}

static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

MKAnnotationView *pinView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

if (pinView == nil)
{
    pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

}
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.annotation = annotation;

DisplayMap *myAnn = (DisplayMap *)annotation;
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myAnn.icon];



// Create a UIButton object to add on the
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[pinView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];

return pinView;
}



 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

 if ([(UIButton*)control buttonType] == UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure)
 {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Prova" sender:view];


}
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Prova"]) {

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = sender;



    DettagliAlberghi *destViewController =(DettagliAlberghi *) segue.destinationViewController;

    DisplayMap *displayMap = (DisplayMap *)annotationView.annotation;



    destViewController.recipe = displayMap;
}
}
```

Comment: I've commented the else statement but have same problem :(

Comment: @DjBeppee try this. If this not work I will need the complete .h and .m, in order to help you property. Ciao

Comment: ok, I added all the missing code to make you understand what I have to do exactly. of course i've added the code that you suggested..but when I simulate the app crash..i don't know what to do .. I'm going crazy

Comment: What message do you receive in the crash ?

Comment: When I click on the pin, the app crashes. I added an NSLog in PrepareToSegue and I noticed that all the fields to export in View next are empty, however, the data is read through PFQuery in viewDidLoad. What's wrong? When I click the pin does not export the data required? (I added the log immediately after the code)

Comment: Ok, I saw now the change that you made :) the problem still is not in view the pin on the map (because the pin must be properly) but when I click on it to go to the next View that does not detect the data to pass :/ I try this code and let you know what it does

Comment: I used the code you wrote to me, but now the pin on the map no longer appear :(

Comment: I`m sorry. I'd like to see your current code. Edit your question and add your current code.

Comment: Add a NSLog in viewDidLoad in order to see the annotation you are adding: Here:   [_mapView addAnnotation:displayMap]; NSLog(@"I'm adding %@ to my %@",[displayMap description],[_mapView description]);

Comment: Have you skype? So maybe we can chat them. However, I added the NSLog and the result is this: **014-12-05 10:52:37.390 Veg[1865:60835] I'm adding <DisplayMap: 0x7fc235f5bb40> to my <MKMapView: 0x7fc235f4e8f0; frame = (0 65; 375 602); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc235f016c0>>
2014-12-05 10:52:37.390 Veg[1865:60835] I'm adding <DisplayMap: 0x7fc2368afe20> to my <MKMapView: 0x7fc235f4e8f0; frame = (0 65; 375 602); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc235f016c0>>** PS: the problem is when I click on one of them that does not send the information

Comment: Now I can't, but if you want put in some repository the project tomorrow.

Comment: Your dettagliAlbergi is blank, in the storyboard the second viewController  doesn't have put its class (dettagliAlbergi I suppose), It´s for that than you app crash, according to storyboard you are creating (A UIViewController, no a dettagliAlbergi) and of course this doesn't respond to selector (setRecipe:).

Comment: Um .. no I created a new project with only the classes where I'm working on it ... in the rush I forgot to add some details ... I add them right away (in the original design is everything and I should import a lot of things )

Comment: DettagliAlberghi.h is not in git  https://github.com/DjBeppee/Veg/blob/master/Veg/DettagliAlberghi.m

Comment: Ok, updated the project to Github **EDIT: ops..now is in git**

Comment: @DjBeppee I'm update the answer. Work,s no fine (you need to work in UI). But It's no bad idea you read a little bit about iOS Dev ( Big Nerd Ranch book is good idea). Best regards.

Comment: As it does not work? The same view the use to pass data from a UITableView and works perfectly. I only have problems with the MapView that I did not pass the data once you click the pin

Comment: You need to click the info button in the callout.

Comment: Oooook finally works properly. Thank you so much, you've been very kind and very helpful :)